# seeding db with users using devise fails: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to run a simple loop to create multiple seed users:

In seeds.rb:

```
5.times do
    user = User.new(
        email: RandomData.random_space_email, 
        password: 'teatea', 
        password_confirmation: 'teatea'
    )
    user.skip_confirmation!
    user.save!
end
```

RandomData.random_space_email:

```
def self.random_space_email
    "#{@@names.sample}@#{@@space_words.sample}.#{@@space_words.sample}"
end
```

When I run `rake db:reset` I get this error: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email is invalid`

however if I set the loop to run only once (`1.times do`) everything works as expected.

Any help would be wonderful!

Comment: Try it    `email=(0..8).map{(‘a’..’z’).to_a[rand(26)]}.join+”@yopmail.com”` for generatig email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully checking:

```
def self.random_space_email
    "#{@@names.sample}@#{@@space_words.sample}.#{@@space_words.sample}"
end
```

I found that `@@space_words` sometimes contains strings with spaces... and this seems to be causing `devise` to throw an error, as there cannot be whitespace in an email address.